# Magento is discounting the entire shopping cart when I have it set to discount specific products. How can I fix this?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, promotions

Here is what I have in the promotions

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
Category  is  40
Pattern  contains  Vanderbilt
Material  contains  Porcelain

I tried to get as specific as possible with the conditions, but it still isn't working and it just applies it to the entire cart as a whole. I have Magento 1.9.0.1 version.

Comment: Are both of the "if all" conditions inside each other?

Comment: Yes, everything is under the first "if all" statement

Answer (score 0):

Their are two different ways you can limit the cart price rules

**Conditions**
Which limits when a rule can be activated

**Actions/Apply rules only to cart items matching the following conditions**
This limits what products in the cart the rule will apply to

---

Reading through your answer it looks like you only set the **Conditions** that means if just one product in the cart is in that category the rest will get the benefit of the rule.

Use the **Actions/Apply rules** to limit what products can get the discount.

Comment: Okay so I went to actions and here is what it looks like...                      Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is  40  
Material  contains  Porcelain  
Pattern  contains  Vanderbilt  
But it is still discounting the entire shopping cart. Each product individually

Comment: If you are using flat products make sure the indexers have run.